# What is the quality standard I'm not meeting with my question?

Tags: discussion, support, question-quality, quality-filter

I can't submit the following question on Stack Overflow:

> I'm using OSClass 3.3.2 and I want to remove the contact form
>   according to a condition, but I can't find it. Which file is it in?

I tried to re-phrase it several times, but upon submission it fails showing the message:

> It does not meet our quality standards

What's wrong with my question?

Comment: By cant submit... You mean posting doesnt work? There should be an error message....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've read that, but I can't see what the problem is

Comment: *"I can't see what the problem is"* ...you don't have one.

Comment: I've submited question many times to SO and never got this problem. Could it be an update issue?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I dont understand your comment. Do you mean my body post doesnt describe a problem?

Comment: @patrice . yes, posting doesnt work. the description just says it does not meet quality standars

Comment: "and it's written with proper grammar"

Comment: It does describe a problem, but somewhat vaguely and without any concrete example to allow others to recreate it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I really dont understand why, the question seems pretty clear to me. I can't give an example because it isnt a problem of an error in the code, is a problem I can't find where a code is located in an already made program

Comment: Its unclear what is stopping you from doing this, its too broad since the "condition" isn't defined. Its asking us to find a resource. Its a problem that doesn't look like it can be reproduced.... You might want to take a look at [ask] too

Comment: So.... I should go look through that program for you? Remember Stack's questions aren't just for you to get your answer. They are to help build a repository of knowledge. I see no value for future visitors to the site (not to mention it really looks like a "debug this for me" type deal)

Comment: @patrice No, you shouldnt. If you already found it, you tell me. That's way easier to do things.

Comment: @Pablo we're not here just to make your life easier. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask], and note that we expect [quite a bit of effort on your part](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3001761).

Comment: @jonrshape I always thought the purpose of a development discussion board was to make development easier, but if you say so, I guess this is the kind of a question you have to ask in another development discussion board with different rules. There is really no purpose in spending days tracking where a code is if someone already made it. Thanks for answering anyway

Comment: @Pablo so... The intent of Stack is to make development easier by asking questions that will be useful to many many more people in the future. We are not a help desk where you can log any request and get it answered. Your question's answer is basically "use a debugger if possible, read through the code, and here is how you figure out your issue". This is something you should be able to do.

Comment: That may well be *"the purpose of a development discussion board"* but **this isn't a development discussion board**.

Answer (score 19):

#### What is the quality standard I'm not meeting with my question?

I suggest it triggers the filter because it is simply too short.

#### Do not try to minimally bypass the filter, it is helping *you*

From [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error):

> **Why do I see a message that my question does not meet quality
> standards?**
>
> Sometimes users encounter the following message when posting a
> question:
>
> > "This post does not meet our quality standards."
>
> If you see this
> message, then your question was automatically blocked by the server.
> All new questions are subjected to a "minimum quality" filter that
> checks for some basic indicators of a good, complete question. Check
> to make sure that your question has the following:
>
> - A clear title.
> - A reasonable explanation of what your question is. Add as much detail as you can.
> - Any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to
>   solve your problem.
> - Correct use of English spelling and grammar to the
>   best of your ability.

These are some of the most common reasons a question is down voted and closed - the filter is preventing that happening to you. Arguably the only bullet points met by the quoted question is "Correct use of English".

#### So what should you do?

Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

No seriously, go read it. The first thing to do, as mentioned on how-to-ask, is "Search, and research". The quoted question can be summarized as:

> In what file is the contact form defined for OSClass?

Let's assume you don't know what to look for in the code (as that is the most obvious way to figure that out).

[Searching for "what file is the contact form defined for OSClass"](https://www.google.com/search?q=In%20what%20file%20is%20the%20contact%20form%20defined%20for%20OSClass%3F&rct=j) has many results, including [this](http://forums.osclass.org/development/modification-of-the-contact-form/), [this](http://forums.osclass.org/general-help/how-to-edit-the-contact-form/) and [this](https://github.com/osclass/Osclass/blob/master/oc-includes/osclass/frm/Contact.form.class.php) - any of which look to answer the question. This suggests little if any research was done. If these found resources really do not immediately answer the question, this kind of info should be *in* the question.

For the question asked to be considered on topic it would need to read more like:

> I'm looking for the code responsible for the contact form in OSClass 3.3.2. I've searched in my local install but I can't seem to figure out where it is, I've also simply searched for bits of the rendered markup (e.g. unique class names used) and they don't appear in any file either. I've looked online and found `[link]` and `[link]` but in my install <some explanation as to why the links don't help>. What is responsible for generating the contact form? When rendered it looks like this:
>
> ```
> <form>...</form>
> ```

It should be clear that asking a question on stack overflow should be more of a last resort, than first port of call when confronted by a code problem. For the topic you're asking about here, the support forum of OSClass is more appropriate.

See also [this similar question on meta stack exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards) for a more elaborated explanation.